# What is a compatible version of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa for spring-data-geode?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-gemfire, geode, spring-data-commons, spring-boot-jpa

Can someone help me find a compatible version of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` for `spring-data-geode` in Spring Boot version `2.1.4.RELEASE`?

This is for an application running an embedded cache server with write-behind implementation connecting to an Oracle RDBMS using HikariCP.

I have tried running my application with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` versions from `2.1.4.RELEASE` down to `2.0.8.RELEASE` with no success. I have also tried versions `2.1.4.RELEASE` down to `2.0.8.RELEASE` for `spring-data-commons`.

Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geodeserverApplication': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AmpsConfig': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#134abd78' of type [org.springframework.data.gemfire.wan.AsyncEventQueueFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'asyncEventQueues' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'regionListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionDBRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.jpmorgan.geode.server.GeodeserverApplication.main(GeodeserverApplication.java:43)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Region': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#134abd78' of type [org.springframework.data.gemfire.wan.AsyncEventQueueFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'asyncEventQueues' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'regionListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ampsConfigDBRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedArray(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'regionListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionDBRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:308)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionDBRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:545)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are some things to be aware of when using "multi-store" support (e.g. JPA with Geode) in a Spring application with *Spring Data's* Repository infrastructure.

This [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/multi-store) loosely talks about it at a high-level.  I tried to find more in the SD Commons [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/), but I did not find anything, surprisingly, since I thought I remember there being information on it; sorry.

I actually modified the "*multi-store*" example, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-data-examples/tree/multi-store-gemfire/multi-store/src/main/java/example/springdata/multistore), sometime ago to investigate multi-store support based on this earlier [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-574) (and this, [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-504)) in SDG, which has since then, been resolved, since SDG `1.9`, in fact, as the JIRA tickets indicate.

Essentially, I think it boils down to how you set your Repository "scan" using the enabling annotations (e.g. `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EnableGemfireRepositories`).

For instance, I have another multi-store [example](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/tree/master/repository-example) (configuration) in my *Contacts Application* Reference Implementation for SDG, which uses GemFire/Geode (of course) and JPA.  Specifically, have a look at the [Geode configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/config/ApplicationConfiguration.java#L49) and then the [JPA configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/config/jpa/JpaConfiguration.java#L55) for the Repository setup.

> NOTE: FYI, [Pivotal GemFire](https://pivotal.io/pivotal-gemfire) and [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/) are interchangeable as of SD Kay (SDG 2.0+).

Essentially, I think it boils down to properly delineating the application Repository interfaces for Geode and JPA by putting them in their own packages and then setting the `basePackageClasses` attribute in each enabling annotation (e.g. `@EnableGemfireRepositories`) appropriately.

As far as version goes...

If your application POM inherits (directly or indirectly) from the Spring Boot Starter parent pom (for [example](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/pom.xml#L8-L12)), and then declares/includes the dependencies without version ([here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/pom.xml#L68-L77) and [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/pom.xml#L98-L101)), you will be sure to be getting the right, curated/harmonized versions ([this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L34-L224) and then [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L225-L3061)) of all SD modules in conjunction with Boot, the core Spring Framework, Spring Data, everything.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

If it does not, please post back again, and perhaps provide a GitHub project with the issue and I can take a closer look.

Cheers!

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that the *mult-store* support documentation is in the SD JPA docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules), go figure, ;-)

Comment: Thank you @John Blum. I had not set the _@EnableGemfireRepositories_ and _@EnableJpaRepositories_ correctly. I was able to resolve this now.